# Returning ObjectResult results in 406 Not Acceptable

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

While following along with Scott Allen's Pluralsight course, "Asp.net Core 1.0 Fundamentals", in the "Controllers in the MVC Framework" module and "Action Results" section I ran into a 406 Not Acceptable error on my Index action method that returned an ObjectResult with a model object.

Answer (score 13):

This [blog post](https://manuel-rauber.com/2016/02/15/back-to-the-roots-creating-thin-webapis-using-the-core-of-aspnet-core/) led me to making a reference to the IMvcCoreBuilder and adding the JSON formatter as follows:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     var mvcCore = services.AddMvcCore();
     mvcCore.AddJsonFormatters();
     services.AddSingleton(provider => Configuration);
     services.AddSingleton<IGreeter, Greeter>();
}
```

which allowed me to continue.

Comment: Why don't you just do this: services.AddMvc();

Comment: You're right. I thought I needed to do this for other reasons during the tutorial, but I made your suggested change and it works. Thank you.

Comment: This solved my issue: services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters()