# ASP.Net Core 2 JSON case conversion

Tags: json, asp.net-core

Hi i am struggling a bit and even after researching all that is out there. I am using ASP.Net Core 2 and found that at lease in version 1, camel case coversion was default. However I notice that by default I am getting Pascal case

So I tried to fix that at startup...

```
                .AddMvcCore()

            .AddJsonOptions(options =>
            {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include;
                options.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            })
            .AddApiExplorer();
```

However it did not work and I get Pascal case. What does work is if I do the same in the controller which I do not want to do for obvious reasons.

```
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(legalTerms, new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
                DefaultValueHandling = DefaultValueHandling.Include,
                NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore
            }
            );
            return Ok(json);
```

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
services
.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("CorsPolicy",
        builder => builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials());
})
.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup))
.AddMvcCore()
.AddJsonFormatters() //this does the work
.AddApiExplorer();
```

[Answered  here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38613714/returning-objectresult-results-in-406-not-acceptable)